# Spring Boot Apache CXF JAX-RS service context path / base URI

Tags: spring-boot, jax-rs, cxf

I configure my JAXRS Server in Spring Boot like so:

```
    JAXRSServerFactoryBean factoryBean = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setBus(this.bus);
    factoryBean.setFeatures(singletonList(swagger2Feature()));
    factoryBean.setServiceBeans(Arrays.asList(blah(), blah2(), blah3()));
    factoryBean.setAddress("/api/v1/"); // HERE

    List<Object> providers = new ArrayList<>();
    providers.add(new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider());
    factoryBean.setProviders(providers);

    BindingFactoryManager manager = factoryBean.getBus().getExtension(BindingFactoryManager.class);
    JAXRSBindingFactory restFactory = new JAXRSBindingFactory();
    restFactory.setBus(factoryBean.getBus());
    manager.registerBindingFactory(JAXRSBindingFactory.JAXRS_BINDING_ID, restFactory);

    return factoryBean.create();
```

However, the URLs always require `/services` in front, which is a nuisance (but not the end of the world). Is there any way I can remove `/services` and just get it deployed to the root context?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have not created your own `CxfServlet` bean you can set the path by setting `cxf.path` property in your application.properties file

```
cxf.path=/
```

Another way is to override `ServletRegistrationBean`.

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean cxfServletRegistration() {
    String urlMapping = "/*";
    ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(
            new CXFServlet(), urlMapping);
    registration.setLoadOnStartup(-1);
    return registration;
}
```